# Disabling Android Up Navigation Depending on the Value of an Intent Extra

Tags: android, android-intent, up-navigation

I am navigating to Android activity A from different activities. Depending on which activity, A is called from, I may or may not want to provide up-navigation on A.

```
intent.putExtra("ShouldProvideUpNav", true); // or false
```

I read this intent extra in A's onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

```
shouldProvideUpNav = intent.getBooleanExtra("ShouldProvideUpNav", false);
```

I am not sure where I should use this boolean to disable the up navigation if the value is false. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from within your onCreate() method.  Depending on what you would like enabled you can set both of these attributes accordingly there.

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

of which you can get your `ActionBar` through `getActionBar()` if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(shouldProvideUpNav);`

Comment: Okay, this hid the caret but still navigates up.